# I'm trying to get a query to get activity, excluding the day of sign up (first occurrence of a specific id)

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a basic table "events" with the row id and date. It shows each time a user interacts (register or login) to a site.

I want to calculate active users per day. But I want to exclude all activity on the day the user signed up.

For now, the same table format but without the ids from the first occurrence would solve my problem.

Comment: do you have any code? it is helpful if you can include code

Comment: you can use a `count(id)` and `where` date is not equal the day the users sign up

Comment: The day the user signed up is the first time the ID shows up. 

`SELECT date, userid FROM consumer.events ORDER BY date, userid`

I need this list but to remove the row where the id shows up for the first time.

Comment: I'm trying to get this list but with the rows of the date where the id shows up for the first time removed

Comment: i have added an answer to your question try it out and tell me if it don't work for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok so what you essentially need for each event is :

1. user_id
2. acitivity_date
3. first_activity_date

You should already have the first two from your events table: for the first_activity_date, you can use a window function to calculate that: Following is a sample query:

```
SELECT
  activity_date,
  COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM (
  SELECT
    user_id,
    activity_date,
    MIN(activity_date) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id) AS first_activity_date
  FROM 
    [project_id:dataset.events] 
)
WHERE
  activity_date != first_activity_date
GROUP BY 
  1
ORDER BY
  1
```

Comment: Thank you. This is the correct answer because it excludes all events of the day of the first day instead of just the first occurrence.

Answer (score 0):

try this out

```
 SELECT date, userid FROM consumer.events WHERE Count(userid) > 1 ORDER BY date, userid
```

**Explanation**

This select statement will limit the query to only show where the `userid` doesn't show up for the first time

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help. A proper explanation [would greatly improve](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please edit your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made